# How to sort a date column in Pandas with value_counts?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in my dataframe like this:

```
      submit_date
1     2020-12-14
3     2020-12-14
4     2020-12-14
5     2020-12-14
29    2020-12-15
     ...    
746   2021-01-12
771   2021-01-12
744   2021-01-12
757   2021-01-12
772   2021-01-12
```

I want to obtain how many submissions are happening per day. Here's the code I've tried:

```
print(df['submit_date'].value_counts())
```

Which results in:

```
2021-01-07    95
2021-01-08    58
2021-01-05    47
2021-01-11    45
2021-01-09    41
2020-12-28    39
2021-01-06    39
2020-12-29    34
2021-01-02    32
2021-01-04    31
2021-01-01    29
2021-01-12    28
2020-12-31    28
2020-12-16    27
2020-12-15    25
2020-12-30    22
2021-01-03    21
2020-12-26    19
2020-12-22    19
2020-12-18    17
2020-12-21    16
2020-12-17    15
2020-12-27    12
2020-12-23    12
2021-01-10     6
2020-12-19     5
2020-12-14     4
2020-12-24     4
2020-12-20     2
Name: submit_date, dtype: int64
```

I want these counts to be sorted by date. So my expected output would be:

```
2020-12-14     4
2020-12-15    25
2020-12-16    27
2020-12-17    15
...
```

I know it's sorting by the value counts but how do I sort by the date instead? I tried df['submit_date'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=True) but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can sorting index [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) :

```
df['submit_date'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Or if original column is sorted add `sort=False` parameter to [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for prevent sorting by counts:

```
df['submit_date'].value_counts(sort=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, which might be overkill, is to use pandas group_by to determine the number of submissions per day.

```
groupby_obj = df.groupby(['submit_date'], as_index=False)
df1 = groupby_obj.size()
```

Followed by a sort

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='submit_date', ascending=True, na_position='first')
```

If writing that code is hard, you could check out [Mito](http://trymito.io/?source=stackoverflow-65704040) (which full disclaimer, I helped build). But its a spreadsheet that generates the production-ready Python code for you. For this use case, you could use our pivot table to group the data by date and then use the sort button to get the data in the correct order!